# Получить SID пользователя asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

Доброго времени суток. 
 
Разрабатываю сайт asp.net для локальной сети. Данные беру из AD (с помощью `DirectoryServices`), и встал вопрос, как получать SID пользователя, заданного пользователя. 
 
Буду еще благодарен, если еще кто подскажет можно ли в `DirectoryServices` исключить определенную папку из поиска.

Comment: смотрите SID в Win32_UserAccount через WMIService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря подсказки [Konst](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177061/konst) набросал решение. функция получает SID исходя из логина пользователя.
 
 
 `Function win32_SID(userlogin As String) As String
        Dim SID As String = ""
        Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
        If objWMIService IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where Domain='DomainName' AND Status='OK' AND Name='" & userlogin & "'")
            For Each objItem In colItems
                SID = "SID - " & objItem.SID
            Next
        End If
        Return SID
End Function`